# Can dynamic DNS clients keep "URL Redirect Records" updated at Namecheap?

Tags: redirects, dns, nameserver, namecheap, dynamic-dns

Can a URL Redirect Record at Namecheap be updated with a dynamic DNS client?

I would like to serve a website on a non-standard port, and thus cannot use a type A record. I would like it to work as follows:

```
t1): server @ x.x.x.x:12345, example.com => x.x.x.x:12345 
t2): server @ y.y.y.y:12345, example.com => y.y.y.y:12345
```

I do not want to have to type `example.com:12345`. I do want to always host at server port 12345.

Type:A DNS records at Namecheap can be updated by a dynamic DNS client. It is well-documented. What about the type: URL Redirect Record records as per the Namecheap web portal? Can a dynamic DNS client change those records? Apparently these are not a real type of record, but simply a convenience.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "URL redirect record" in DNS. When you select that record type at Namecehap, it just means that they run a webserver for you that issues redirects.   The DNS points to their server.   Namecheap is obfuscating what actually happens to make things appear "simpler."

Comment: Users will still see the URL with the IP address and port number in it.  If they try to bookmark or link to your site, the links will break at the next dynamic DNS update.  Search engines won't be able to index your domain, they will only see the IP address and port.  So your site will keep falling out of search engines.   How will anybody even know to use the domain name?  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: "thus cannot use a type A record" You always need an `A` record to map a name to an IP address. The port part is handled outside of the DNS (because sadly browsers do not take into account `SRV` records)